# Erro com select no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo um log de erro que não acontece freqüentemente. Em média 1 vez por mês. O problema é que não estou identificando o erro. Vou posta meu select para vcs poderem ver se tem algo errado.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT SUM(a.qtd)
    FROM 
        produtos_pedidos a, 
        pedidos b
    WHERE 
        a.id_pedido = b.id 
        and (b.status = 0 or b.status = 4 or b.status = 7)
        and a.id_produto = $produto
        and b.pdv = 'n'
");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$qtd_penhora = (float) $row['SUM(a.qtd)'];
```

O log de erro e esse aqui:

```
[09-Jan-2017 16:56:55 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/Funcoes/Movimentacao.php on line 35
```

A linha que ocorre e erro e essa aqui:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Tem alguma coisa errada no select?

Comment: Coloque sua consulta em uma variável. E dá um echo `$query`. Pegue o retorno e rode em seu SGBD. Veja se retorna resultados ou não. O que não pode é dar erro. Aparentemente está certo. Não sei como você está fazendo a conexão.

Comment: bom vou testar isso que vc falou.

Answer (score 1):

Significa que sua query não está sendo executada corretamente.

Coloque estas linhas antes do fetch_array() para descobrir qual o erro:

```
if (!$result)
   die ($mysqli->error);
```

Comment: nesse caso ele vai retornar um erro na tela. e eu desabilitei isso no servidor, como faço para ele retornar o erro no log?

Comment: die funciona como o exit, imprime uma mensagem e finaliza a execução. O PHP não irá considerar um erro, portanto a mensagem será exibida na tela.

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim, usando o [fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

```
$mysqli->query("
    SELECT SUM(a.qtd)
    FROM 
        produtos_pedidos a, 
        pedidos b
    WHERE 
        a.id_pedido = b.id 
        and (b.status = 0 or b.status = 4 or b.status = 7)
        and a.id_produto = $produto
        and b.pdv = 'n'
");
$row = $mysqli->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: o que o fetch_all faz de diferente?

Comment: Então, sempre usei dessa maneira (quando não uso framework como laravel ou codeigniter). 
Ele simplesmente traz os dados em forma de array, onde os indexes são os nomes das colunas.

Podendo usar os seguintes parâmetros: **MYSQLI_ASSOC**, **MYSQLI_NUM**, ou **MYSQLI_BOTH**. Onde o **mysqli_assoc** faz o que eu disse, o **mysqli_num** faz com que os indexes sejam números, e o **mysqli_both** traz os dois (números e nomes).